# IL2CPP is not compiled

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, il2cpp

Errors:

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\WinPlayerBuildProgram\ei6vj\1ry7gboqrevb.obj failed with output:
u3gs8cy93io00.lump.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(10): fatal error C1083: ???? ?????? ?? ???????: vcruntime.h: No such file or directory,

UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)
```

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\WinPlayerBuildProgram\ei6vj\09u9hohoktxr.obj failed with output:
4grclefi1deu0.lump.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(10): fatal error C1083: ???? ?????? ?? ???????: vcruntime.h: No such file or directory,

UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)
```

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\WinPlayerBuildProgram\ei6vj\mx6emxwljcyf.obj failed with output:
ru3a7e9s4nrg3.lump.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(10): fatal error C1083: ???? ?????? ?? ???????: vcruntime.h: No such file or directory,

UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)
```

... (12 errors)

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 75 seconds (75011 ms)
15 errors
UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int)
```

I tried reinstalling the Windows 10 SDK.
I tried using the standard render pipeline.

Comment: you need to get to the bottom of what file/folder is missing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I found vcruntime.h in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include and copied it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt.